# symfony component appends data to session and corrupts the data

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached, symfony4

In our application we're sharing session data between a new decoupled application built with symfony 4.3 and old legacy code. Both codebases operate the session data in memcached servers. In the symfony app we're using `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler` to handle the data and we overrode two methods of it to populate the default symfony session bag called `_sf2_attributes`, these two methods look like:

```
   * Symfony attributes bag key
   */
  const SF_ATTRIBUTES_BAG_KEY = '_sf2_attributes';

  /**
   * read session from memcached
   *
   * @param string $sessionId Id of session
   *
   * @return string
   */
  protected function doRead($sessionId) {
    $data = parent::doRead($sessionId);

    return serialize(
        [
        self::SF_ATTRIBUTES_BAG_KEY => empty($data) ? [] : unserialize($data)
        ]
    );
  }

  /**
   * Write session data into session
   *
   * @param string $sessionId id of  session
   * @param string $data      data to write
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function doWrite($sessionId, $data) {
    $data = unserialize($data);
    $data = array_key_exists(self::SF_ATTRIBUTES_BAG_KEY, $data) ? $data[self::SF_ATTRIBUTES_BAG_KEY] : [];

    return parent::doWrite($sessionId, serialize($data));
  }
```

However, at some point, completely randomly the session data could not be read. When hitting this and debugging by querying memcached for my session, I see the data is corrupted there and looks like

```
631:"O:37:"Namespace\Namespace2\Models\U %_S�<_`":17@d
16:"is_auth iicated�^8�dmi�q13�_view�+1 ~
```

and so on. Comparing it with the "normal" session data right after session refresh I see the only difference: the corrupted data contains the following: ``` Symfony\Comp �nt\S�-\Guard\TD�\BSA�"``":394:{a#�!�@� t�jD�*��Of�App�bCo" .{ �!/*!j�*_ $ȤI*H b��GU@x�(@]�"@�"O r'
                                                         �O@1!ROLE_ADMIDn} R!�1 Z2 �$�@(O:4 ��.C%�\Gk`+@@�4!b� 4`�A�1�
�3 �FW#      ]@�s�
*}}";} ``` which probably means that `Symfony\Component\Guard`, which we're using is appending some data, calling our overwritten `doWrite` and corrupting the data.

Questions:

1. Is there an event when the guard component appends the data into the session? We don't save anything ourselves in the session guard authenticator, just reading the data. We need to get steps to reproduce this
2. Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: deserializing is arbitrarily *hard* and as far as I can tell from your code, you assume `serialize(unserialize($string)) === $string`, which I wouldn't assume at all and generally should be assumed to be FALSE.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi , we basically wanted to populate the default symfony session attribute bag with the values deserialized from the shared session storage. Do you mean we should use symfony's normalizer and serializer ? Will in this case serialize+deserialize produce the same string? The problem is: we cannot break the other app session data that uses `php-serialize` builtin functionality to populate `$_SESSION` superglobal

Comment: is there any reason, why you don't just write/read your data to an additional key? like ... `parent::doWrite($sessionId.'_custom', $customData)`? (and read, and also add `doDestroy` and `updateTimestamp`)

Comment: I think we want to access our data with just session component injected anywhere and `::loadSession()` of `NativeSessionStorage` won't populate it unless the session data coming from the legacy app has all the keys inside `_sf2_attributes` namespace (symfony bag) , and it doesn't and we can't change it.